# Replace two bytes in a generic list

Tags: c#, .net

I want to replace every occurrence of one of those magic 2-byte packages in my `List<byte>` with a single byte:

> { 0xF8, 0x00 } -> Replace with 0xF8
>   { 0xF8, 0x01 } -> Replace with 0xFB
>   { 0xF8, 0x02 } -> Replace with 0xFD
>   { 0xF8, 0x03 } -> Replace with 0xFE

For example:

```
List<byte> message 
    = new List<byte> { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xF8, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x02, 0xF8, 0x03, 0xFE };

// will be converted to:

List<byte> expected 
    = new List<byte> { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xF8, 0xFB, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFE };
```

---

This is my solution so far, which works but I don't like it because its readability is quite bad:

```
public static void RemoveEscapeSequences(List<byte> message)
{
    // skipped parameter checks
    for (int index = 0; index < message.Count - 1; ++index)
    {
        if (message[index] == 0xF8)
        {
            // found an escaped byte, look at the following byte to determine replacement
            switch (message[index + 1])
            {
                case 0x0:
                    message[index] = 0xF8;
                    message.RemoveAt(index + 1);
                    break;
                case 0x1:
                    message[index] = 0xFB;
                    message.RemoveAt(index + 1);
                    break;
                case 0x2:
                    message[index] = 0xFD;
                    message.RemoveAt(index + 1);
                    break;
                case 0x3:
                    message[index] = 0xFE;
                    message.RemoveAt(index + 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter solution with improved readability?

Comment: Don't know about shorter, but it'd be much *faster* if you create a new list and keep adding items to it, rather than repeatedly calling List.RemoveAt() which is an O(N) operation, giving your algorithm an O(N^2) complexity!

Comment: Is performance important for you? What is average size of a list?

Comment: Performance is unimportant, message length is about 20 bytes

Comment: @nabulke if you want really readable code, it would be nice if you will explain what those message is and why you need to replace some 2-byte packages. Why first byte is always 0xFB? And why packages only two byte length? We need to understand intent of this replacement in order to make it understandable for others.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Those are data bytes received by serial port. Some bytes are used for controlling the data stream (like start of message, end of message and so on). If those control bytes occur inside the data payload, they have to be escaped to avoid confusion. The complete message has a fixed pre- and suffix, thats why they always start and end the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this - it'll be slightly slower, though:

```
public static void RemoveEscapeSequences(List<byte> message)
{
    var replaceBytes = new Dictionary<byte, byte>()
    {
        {0x00, 0xF8}, {0x01, 0xFB}, {0x02, 0xFD}, {0x03, 0xFE}
    };

    // skipped parameter checks
    for (int index = 0; index < message.Count - 1; ++index)
    {
        if (message[index] == 0xF8)
        {
            if(replaceBytes.ContainsKey(message[index + 1]))
            {
                message[index] = replaceBytes[message[index + 1]];
                message.RemoveAt(index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marcin: The question is about better readability, better readability in most cases is tradeoff with performance

Comment: @Phil: please provide an example whcih causes a problem using current `for` loop. I believe problems will be in case of `foreach` or

Comment: Ok, I've removed my comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> Escape(this IEnumerable<byte> source)
{
    if (source == null)     
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            byte current = enumerator.Current;

            if (current != 0xF8)
            {
                yield return current;
                continue;
            }

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield return current;

            byte next = enumerator.Current;

            switch (next)
            {
                case 0x00: yield return 0xF8; break;
                case 0x01: yield return 0xFB; break;
                case 0x02: yield return 0xFD; break;
                case 0x03: yield return 0xFE; break;
                default:
                    yield return current;
                    yield return next;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<byte> result = message.Escape().ToList();

foreach(var b in message.Escape())
     Console.Write("0x{0:x} ", b);
```

Comment: You should really dispose the enumerator

Comment: @Phil agree, I'll add that in a moment

Comment: Maybe it's just me but this is even more code and much less straightforward than what the OP currently has and even complicates the client code by needing to call `.ToList()`.

Comment: @Esailija Agree, much less readable than the OP version IMHO.

Comment: Don't know guys, for me `current` and `next` is much more readable, then indexing and `for` loop. Also this code is streaming, which is benefit if you need to loop over elements. And logic now is straight forward, without removing items at some positions. You just return them and going further

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Probably a matter of personal preferences / habits, but the multiple yields are less readable for me. Actually, the whole enumerator stuff instead of a simple loop is less readable in this case, IMHO.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The OP's current code would be even simpler if he returned a new list instead of in-place modification, that has nothing to do with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple/understandable version, that should be efficient too:

```
private static List<byte> ComputeBytes(List<byte> input)
{
    byte magicValueFirstByte = 0xF8;
    var secondByteToBeReplaced = new List<byte> { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    var replacements = new List<byte> { 0xF8, 0xFB, 0xFD, 0xFE };

    var output = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentValue = input[i];
        if (currentValue == magicValueFirstByte && i < input.Count - 1)
        {
            int index = secondByteToBeReplaced.IndexOf(input[i + 1]);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                // Then when must replace
                output.Add(replacements[index]);

                // Skip next item
                i++;

                continue;
            }
        }

        // Won't replace value, so add current one
        output.Add(currentValue);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: It's so readable that you added three lines of comments which describe what's happening? :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky So a readable code is a code without comments? Or it's readable *because of the lack* of comments? Really? Do note that a line of comment is *also* a line of code, and it fully participates to make the whole block readable.

Comment: actually line of comment is a form of duplication of code. It expresses intent of code, which can't express intent by itself :) I never said that code without comments is readable. I said that code *with* comments can't express itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the replacement bytes in a small array?

```
private static byte[] EscapeBytes = new byte[]
{
    /* 0x00 */ 0xF8,
    /* 0x01 */ 0xFB,
    /* 0x02 */ 0xFD,
    /* 0x03 */ 0xFE
};
```

Then you can simply index the array:

```
public static List<byte> RemoveEscapeSequences(List<byte> message)
{
    List<byte> result = new List<byte>(message.Count);
    bool escape = false;
    foreach (byte value in message)
    {
        if (escape)
        {
            escape = false;
            // Replace the byte. NOTE 1!
            result.Add(EscapeBytes[value]);
        }
        else if (value == 0xF8)
        {
            // Started an escape sequence.
            escape = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Just add the byte.
            result.Add(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

By adding the bytes to a new list whose capacity is already sufficient to hold the result, you even get a little bit more performance and a lot more readability.

**Note 1**: When the byte after the `0xF8` escape byte is not between 0 and 3, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` will occur. If you care, you'll have to add a small check to see whether the byte value is within range, and decide on what to do if its not (not replacing the bytes, removing the escape, throwing an exception).